# Google Analytics weekly total user count is not match compared to adding daily user count within a week

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have been using Google Analytics API v3 and found that the weekly total user count is different compared with adding daily user count within a week. Following is my API quires.

Weekly query.

```
 "query": {
  "start-date": "2013-01-01",
  "end-date": "2013-12-31",
  "ids": "ga:xxxxxxxx",
  "dimensions": "ga:week",
  "metrics": [
   "ga:users"
  ],
  "start-index": 1,
  "max-results": 1000
 }
```

Daily query.

```
"query": {
  "start-date": "2013-01-01",
  "end-date": "2013-12-31",
  "ids": "ga:xxxxxxxx",
  "dimensions": "ga:week",
  "metrics": [
   "ga:users"
  ],
  "start-index": 1,
  "max-results": 1000
 }
```

What I understood is, when records are grouping together, the total user count is less wheres daily wise weekly user count is higher.

Comment: I'm not familliar with the api but could it be counting unique visitors? So if someone vists on two different days they will be counted twice for the daily query but just once for the weekly.

Comment: That can be the problem but need to verify because Google API document is not mentioned about it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. I can't believe this doesn't have an answer.